# mysql group by two columns either way

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Is it possible to use group by for two columns where they can be group either way?

Example:

```
MyTable

Column1 | Column2
      1         2
      2         1
      1         3
      3         1
      3         2
      4         5
```

Result:

```
Column1 | Column2
      1         2
      1         3
      3         2
      4         5
```

As you can see, it groups the 2 columns even though interchanged. but should still get the rows that doesn't have a partner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
least(Column1, Column2),
greatest(Column1, Column2)
from
Table1
group by 
least(Column1, Column2),
greatest(Column1, Column2)
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29668/1/0)
- read more about the functions [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest)

Comment: I see, didn't know that using least and greatest could achieve this. Good day.